# Does the CLR have the same behavior in both the .Net Framework and the .Net Core?

Tags: .net, .net-core, clr, difference, .net-framework-version

Is CLR has the same behavior in both the .Net Framework and the .Net Core? Or at least how many differences are there (maybe it is possible to distinguish the main points which are different)?

I am reading the **CLR via C# (4th edition), Jeffrey Richter** and during covering the material in the book and searching on the internet the explanations of the not very clearly explained in the book points I come to an understanding that the book assumes that I am working with the .Net Framework (e.g. the GAC topic is present in the book, while the .Net Core does not have such a concept as the GAC).

So, I am curious whether or not it is useful for me to figure out and learn the inners of the CLR as they are presented in the book if I am going to work only with the .Net Core.

Comment: It is close enough, CoreCLR just has features missing.  You'll always find out.

Comment: Historically, .NET Core's CLR is derived from .NET Framework and certain features are removed (GAC, remoting, and so on). As long as you know how .NET Framework works internally, the knowledge can easily apply to .NET Core. Videos like https://www.infoq.com/presentations/clr-coreclr/ might help you get more insights.